# Excel VBA copy from one sheet to another wb doesnt overwrite data

Tags: vba, excel

I use vba to import data from one wb to another - but it seems like the data is not overwriten.

ex.

wb 1 cell A2 contains the number "2" and is copied to wb 2 cell A2.
But if I delete cell A2 from wb 2, and run the vba again - there is no data entered in wb 2 cell A2...
Can anyone see why this is?

Regards
Brian

Sorry forgot to add code :o)

```
Sub GetData()
Dim strWhereToCopy As String, strStartCellColName As String
Dim strListSheet As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

strListSheet = "List"

On Error GoTo ErrH
Sheets(strListSheet).Select
Range("B2").Select

'this is the main loop, we will open the files one by one and copy their data into the masterdata sheet
Set currentWB = ActiveWorkbook
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

    strFileName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) & ActiveCell.Value
    strCopyRange = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) & ":" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)

    strWhereToCopy = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
    strStartCellColName = Mid(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5), 2, 1)

    Application.Workbooks.Open strFileName, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True
    Set dataWB = ActiveWorkbook

    Range(strCopyRange).Select
    Selection.Copy

    currentWB.Activate
    Sheets(strWhereToCopy).Select
    lastRow = LastRowInOneColumn(strStartCellColName)
    Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    dataWB.Close False
    Sheets(strListSheet).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop
Sheets(strListSheet).Select
Range("B2").Select
Exit Sub

ErrH:
MsgBox "It seems some file was missing. The data copy operation is not complete."
Exit Sub
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: not without seeing some code.

Comment: My guess is you are using ActiveWorkbook instead of setting specific references to the two workbooks.

Answer (score 1):

you can copy wb1 and past it as wb2

```
Sub Copy_One_File()

        Dim  wb1, wb2 As String
        wb1 = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "wb1.xlsm"
        wb2 = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "wb2.xlsm"
        FileCopy wb1, wb2

End Sub
```

this is the simplest method

Comment: Thanks. This was a very nice simple example - but I'm not only copying one single wb into a new. I'm trying to combine several sheets from different wb's - in one large sheet in a new wb

Answer (score 0):

you should avoid `Select`/`Selection`/`Activate`/`ActiveXXX`pattern in favour of a fully qualified range reference

like in the following (commented) code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetData()
    Dim strWhereToCopy As String, strStartCellColName As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strCopyRange As Range, cell As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    With Sheets("List") '<--| reference your "List" worksheet
        For Each cell In .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| loop through its column "B" not empty cells form row 2 down to last not empty one
            With cell '<--| reference current cell
                strFileName = .Offset(0, 1) & .Value
                strCopyRange = .Offset(0, 2) & ":" & .Offset(0, 3)
                strWhereToCopy = .Offset(0, 4).Value
                strStartCellColName = Mid(.Offset(0, 5), 2, 1)
            End With

            On Error GoTo ErrH '<--| activate error handler for subsequent file open statement
            Workbooks.Open strFileName, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True
            On Error GoTo 0 '<--| resume "default" error handling

            Range(strCopyRange).Copy '<-- without a leading dot (.) the range referes to the currently active worksheet, which is the active one in the just opened workbook
            With .Parent '<--| reference workbook where currently referenced Sheet "List" resides in
                LastRow = LastRowInOneColumn(.Worksheets(strWhereToCopy), strStartCellColName) '<--| your 'LastRowInOneColumn' function must be passed a worksheet reference, too
                With .Worksheets(strWhereToCopy).Cells(LastRow + 1, 1) '<--| reference 'strWhereToCopy' named worksheet in the referenced workbook
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
                    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End With
            End With
            ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        Next cell
        .Activate
        .Range("B2").Select
    End With
    Exit Sub

ErrH:
    MsgBox "It seems some file was missing. The data copy operation is not complete."

End Sub
```

as per comments, your `LastRowInOneColumn` function must be passed a `worksheet` object reference too and fully qualify the column range reference to search the last row in

the function *signature* and its pseudocode is:

```
Function LastRowInOneColumn(sht As Worksheet, strStartCellColName As String) As Long
    With sht

        'here goes your actual 'LastRowInOneColumn' code
        ' only you have to put a dot (.) before each range reference

    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. My wb2 has 2 sheets. Sheet1 ("List") and Sheet2 ("Samlet status"). Sheet 1 contains cells with filename and full path and data range of start/end cell of the wb's to import data from. Basicly I have a lot of wb's from different dir, containing a lot of data in 5 column. (except the top row.) And I'm trying to collect all that data in one large sheet in a new wb. I've just started to learn about vba so I'm not following you... :o( I'm a totally newbee

Comment: Well just type in my code and have it run. And watch what happens

Comment: @Brian, did you get through it?